# C# Excel OutOfMemory exception caused by inserting to a range

Tags: c#, excel, memory, out-of-memory, vsto

I've been working on a quite complex C# VSTO project that does *a lot* of different things in Excel. However, I have recently stumbled upon a problem I have no idea how to solve. I'm afraid that putting the whole project here will overcomplicate my question and confuse everyone so this is the part with the problem:

```
//this is a simplified version of Range declaration which I am 100% confident in
Range range = worksheet.Range[firstCell, lastCell] 

range.Formula = array; 
//where array is a object[,] which basically contains only strings and also works perfeclty fine
```

The last line that is supposed to insert a [,] array to an Excel range used to work before for smaller Excel books, but now crashes for bigger books with a `System.OutOfMemoryException: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program` and I have no idea why, because it used to work with arrays as long as 500+ elements for one of its dimensions whereas now it crashes for an array with under 400 elements. Furthermore, the RAM usage is about 1.2GB at the moment of crash and I know this project is capable of running perfectly fine with the RAM usage of ~3GBs.

I have tried the following things: inserting this array row by row, then inserting it cell by cell, calling GC.Collect() before each insertion of a row or a cell but it would nonetheless crash with a `System.OutOfMemoryException`.

So I would appreciate any help in solving this problem or identifying where the error could possibly be hiding, because I can't wrap my head around why it refuses to work for arrays with smaller length (but maybe with slightly bigger contents) at the RAM usage level of 1.2GBs which is like 1/3 of what it used to handle. Thank you!

**EDIT**

I've been told in the comments that the code above might be too sparse, so here is a more detailed version (I hope it's not too confusing):

```
List<object[][]> controlsList = new List<object[][]>();
// this list is filled with a quite long method calling a lot of other functions
// if other parts look fine, I guess I'll have to investigate it

int totalRows = 1;

foreach (var control in controlsList)
{
    if (control.Length == 0)
        continue;

    var range = worksheet.GetRange(totalRows + 1, 1, totalRows += control.Length, 11);
    //control is an object[n][11] so normally there are no index issues with inserting
    range.Formula = control.To2dArray();
}

//GetRange and To2dArray are extension methods
public static Range GetRange(this Worksheet sheet, int firstRow, int firstColumn, int lastRow, int lastColumn)
{
    var firstCell = sheet.GetRange(firstRow, firstColumn);
    var lastCell = sheet.GetRange(lastRow, lastColumn);

    return (Range)sheet.Range[firstCell, lastCell];
}

public static Range GetRange(this Worksheet sheet, int row, int col) => (Range)sheet.CheckIsPositive(row, col).Cells[row, col];

public static T CheckIsPositive<T>(this T returnedValue, params int[] vals)
{
    if (vals.Any(x => x <= 0))
        throw new ArgumentException("Values must be positive");

    return returnedValue;
}

public static T[,] To2dArray<T>(this T[][] source)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    int l1 = source.Length;
    int l2 = source[0].Length(1);

    T[,] result = new T[l1, l2];

    for (int i = 0; i < l1; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < l2; ++j)
            result[i, j] = source[i][j];

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What are the values of `firstCell` and `lastCell`? What are the size of the dimensions of `array`? What sort of objects are in the jagged array? The code seems a bit too sparse to rule out the values just being too big and causing an issue because of that.

Comment: often the quickest way to find what is causing a problem like this is to use a profiler and look at the heap while it's running. If you have vs enterprise it has a built in profiler, if not grab a third party profiler.  Note also you can't compare debug and release behavior.  As @MartinCostello said it's hard to offer much without more details around exactly how big range is and what is in array.

Comment: Are you aiming to insert the contents of the Array into each cell in the specified Range?

Comment: @MartinCostello I provided the code related to the problem in the edit, thank you! Hopefully the issue does not lie in the list filling method (that I have not posted) because it does not crash there and it is quite difficult to investigate due to its complexity.

Comment: @MikeJ Are there any specific things to look out for in the heap? I am not quite familiar with memory handling, so I would appreciate if you point out what could be leading to memory leakage (I added some code in the edit), thank you!

Comment: @NautMeg Yes, I have a N x M array which I would like to insert into a N x M range cell by cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure I figured it out correctly, but it seems like the issue lies within Interop.Excel/Excel limitations and the length of formulas I'm trying to insert: whenever the length approaches 8k characters, which is close to Excel limit for the formula contents, the `System.OutOfMemoryException` pops out. When I opted to leave lengthy formulas out, the program started working fine.